# What is the role of DesiredAcuracy and DistanceFilter in CoreLocation, ios

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, core-location

I am Picking GPS coordinates of the user as he walks from CoreLocation in an ios project, I want to pick Lats&longs say for every 1 meter or for every 10 seconds ,

Can I use  DesiredAcuracy and DistanceFilter to do so?

if not What these 2 (DesiredAcuracy and DistanceFilter) will actually do?

Or should I create my own timer to do It?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979319/difference-between-desiredaccuracy-and-distancefilter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can I use DesiredAcuracy and DistanceFilter to do so?**
Yes, according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer):

*DesiredAcuracy*

> The receiver does its best to achieve the requested accuracy; however, the actual accuracy is not guaranteed.
>
> You should assign a value to this property that is appropriate for your usage scenario. For example, if you need the current location only within a kilometer, you should specify `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer` and not `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`. Determining a location with greater accuracy requires more time and more power.

In your case, you should use `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer` for unplugged devices (for example. the user uses it to run distances) or  `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` for plugged in devices (for example, in a car)

`kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`

> Use the highest possible accuracy and combine it with additional sensor data. This level of accuracy is intended for use in navigation applications that require precise position information at all times and are intended to be used only while the device is plugged in.

`kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer`

> Accurate to the nearest kilometer.
>   Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

`kCLLocationAccuracyBest`

> Use the highest-level of accuracy.
>   Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

*DistanceFilter*

> This distance is measured relative to the previously delivered location. >Use the value `kCLDistanceFilterNone` to be notified of all movements. The default value of this property is `kCLDistanceFilterNone`.

So, if you need frequent distance updates (that is, how much distance the user must move to receive an update), you should use `kCLDistanceFilterNone`.

Comment: Thanx for your reply @Erakk , So If I set DistanceFilter to some 10Meters , Location updated delegate is triggered for every 10 meters correct?

Comment: Yes, but apple itself says that, for example, 10 meters will be its target accuracy, but you might get 9 meters updates and 11 meters updates.

Comment: Just an extra: `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` works in any situation, not plugged in only. The issue is that it hogs too much battery power due to the extra processing required for the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Core Location Framework. So don't forget to Add & import Core Location Framework .

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];

CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];

CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];

//Distance in Meters
//1 meter == 100 centimeter
//1 meter == 3.280 feet
//1 square meter == 10.76 square feet
```